# Mac Mini with Intel HD 5000 or Intel Iris Graphics, what exactly is supported OpenGL version?

Tags: macos, opengl

Apple's site does not appear to have the information.  I found a site that says Intel HD Graphics 5000 supports DX11.1 and OpenGL4.0.  Anyone have specific information about the exact OpenGL version for the Mac Mini with either of these graphics options?  I want to upgrade from my older Mac Mini but require support for compute shaders (GPGPU), which means OpenGL 4.3 or later.

Comment: Do you have the specific processor model? if so you can check on intel's  website. On OSX you usually get the processor model with the command ` sysctl -a | grep machdep.cpu`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On OSX, OpenGL is part of the Operating System API. As a result, the OpenGL version is limited by the OSX version *no matter what the GPU is capable of*.

Currenly (as of mid 2015), OSX 10.10 will support at most GL 4.1. *There is no support for OpenGL compute shaders at all*, on this platform.

Have a look at [Apple's OpenGL capabilities tabe](https://developer.apple.com/opengl/capabilities/) for more details. (Version 10.10 is not in this table currently, but the GL 4.1 limit applies there, too).

Comment: Thanks.  I did not realize how limited the Macs are.  At least the ARB extension list shows that Intel Iris has 64-bit floating-point support.  Guess I'll have to resort to computing with framebuffer objects and fragment shaders.